# Pinterest iOS sharing extension stuck on "Pick Image..."

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, pinterest

I'm working on an iOS app which has a "Share with..." option. This share with option presents a `UIActivityViewController` to the user. When the user picks the "Pinterest" button, a new view controller is shown (the Printerest share extension view controller) and then gets stuck on the "Pick Image..." screen (screenshot attached). I'm not sure what the problem is since the same code works for all other extensions I've seen.

Here's the code:

```
UIImage* image = <image here>;
NSURL* url = <image url here>;
UIActivityViewController* vc = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[ image, url ] applicationActivities:nil];
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong. Is this a Pinterest issue or is it my issue?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code with this question url and it is working fine:
[pinterest code test image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3Wfg.png)

You have to check your url and your image is not nil and be sure to configure your pinterest app in your device.

Comment: I've check the image and the URL, both are good and valid. I tried with only the image and i get the same result. It works with all other share extensions i've tried ( facebook, messages, etc, ... ). The pinterest app is also configured correctly since i can use it in other apps to share other images ( such as from the build in Photos app ).